# Trouble reading related data in details page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have tried muplitple approaches here, but I am still not understanding how I can access the data from my join-table in MVC.

Here are my models:

```
public class Company
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Firm> Firm { get; set; }
}

public class Firm
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirmName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Company> Company { get; set; }
    }
```

This creates the join-table "FirmCompany" in my database with "Firm_ID" and "Company_ID".

I have added one record to this table with data "645" and "330" respectively.

In my controller I have the following code to get the data:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Company company = db.Company.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == id);
        var companies = company.Firm;

        if (company == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(companies);
    }
```

When I enter the details view for the correct company I get the following error:

[image]

If I try this approach in my controller:

```
if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Company company = db.Company.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == id);

        if (company == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(company);
```

I just get this text in my view:
System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[KPForms.Models.Company]

Any tips as to where I am going wrong?

**Edit**:
I have tried numerous flavours in the view as well.
Current code in view:

```
    <div>
    <h4>Company</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CompanyName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CompanyName)
        </dd>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Firm)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Also tried a foreach in the view:

```
    <div>
    <h4>Company</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CompanyName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CompanyName)
        </dd>
        <dd>
            @foreach (var item in Model) {
                @Html.Displayfor(item => item.Firm)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to provide an answer, but without the code from your view it's very hard. So please provide what you have in your .cshtml file (your view)

Comment: Are you sure the code you shared is causing the error ? The code you shared is sending a company object to view. Your error says the view is getting something else! You are definitely not sharing some of the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it would be nice to see what your View code looks like.

Not having that, I thought I would provide you with a working solution:

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Company company = db.Company.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == id);

    if (company == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(company);
}
```

**View:**

```
@model KPForms.Models.Company
<p>Company: @Model.CompanyName</p>
<p>Firms:</p>
<ul>
@foreach(var firm in Model.Firm){
    <li>@firm.FirstName</li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me what Stack Overflow can achieve even with wrong information. I have added my original view-code now, but with a small modification to yours it is now working. I was using the wrong item in my foreach loop - trying to loop through the entire company object instead of just firms.